# Interaction.CreateObject creating the old Object

Tags: c#, .net

I am converting a VB6 Application to C#.net and working on Shared Add Ins. On clicking a button in MS Word i want to open my Application, for it i am creating an object of a class like this.

```
objApp = Interaction.CreateObject("DocSys.Application");
```

but this line of code always return old vb6 application instace while i am adding the refrance of .net project.
   what i should do to get the .net object.

Comment: Been a while since I messed with VB6 and its COM support, but perhaps this has something to do with the Running Object Table, where shared program instances are registered? Try to read up on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table

Comment: @Shahar-Kashtan i am completely away of this concept, please help me what i shoud do.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to fumble this.  Forgetting to make your interface and classes [ComVisible(true)] for example.  Or forgetting to register the COM server, explicitly done with Regasm.exe /codebase /tlb.  Or using the wrong version of Regasm.exe, the 64-bit version will write the wrong registry keys.

More relevant to CreateObject(), the [ProgId] attribute on your C# class is essential to ensure you create an exact substitute for the VB6 server.  If the client code ever uses early binding then it is essential that the [Guid] attribute on your interfaces and classes is an *exact* match with the guids used by the VB6 server.  And of course the methods and properties must *exactly* match the ones used by the VB6 server, the order is also very important.

The best way to compare the orange with the apple is to use the Oleview.exe utility.  Run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt and use File + View Typelib.  Select your VB6 server first.  Copy/paste the IDL you see in a text file and save it so you don't have to do this repeatedly.

Run tlbexp.exe on your C# assembly to create the type library for your C# server.  Run Oleview.exe again and select that .tlb file.  Now you can compare the IDL for your server against the one from the VB6 server.  Be sure you get an exact match on the guids, methods and properties.

---

Last but not least, if the client code actually uses Interaction.CreateObject() then it is a .NET application.  Which means that you should not create a [ComVisible] COM server at all.  It should be a regular .NET assembly, just add the reference to it and use the public class directly.