# Get full path of multiple instances running from a program using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

There's an analysis software I'm using that can run multiple instances. It's just like Excel that can run multiple instances of .xls files or Autocad that can run multiple .dwg files.

I've already searched that both Excel and Autocad have API's that can get the full path of all running instances.  However, the API of the software I'm using can only get the full path of the first instance.

What I've already tried is to get the full path of the analysis software using processes. But what I want to do is to be able to get the full path of all running instances and not the path of the analysis software.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not certain that I fully understand your goal, but I think what you want to do is to enumerate the "Running Object Table".  You mentioned Excel; office apps only register the 1st instance in the ROT, but they also register the document.  see the notes section: [How To Attach to a Running Instance of an Office Application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238975) to see if this describes what you want to do.

Comment: @TnTinMn, 

Thanks for the reply.  Sorry if what I wrote wasn't clear.  I'm actually just an enthusiast novice programmer so I hope you bear with me. XD

I've used Excel as an example to explain what I wanted to do. But the analysis software I'm referring to is called STAAD which is an engineering software.  STAAD opens *.std files for each structural model.

I've succeeded in getting the path of the base software STAAD (e.g. C:\STAAD\staad.exe).

Comment: But what I wanted to be able to do is get the path of all running instances of it.  For example, I have 2 files opened namely Str1.std and Str2.std.  

What I want is to be able to get these files directory like D:\Projects\str1.std or D:\Proposals\str2.std.

From what I've read in the link you gave me, even excel only recognizes the first instance but there's a workaround which I completely cannot understand. :(

Comment: I gave you the key words to search and try: "Enumerate the Running Object Table".  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table).  Yes the code is in C#, but there are many free C# to VB converters available.  Give the code a try to see if the information you seek is available in the ROT.  It may not be there.  If it is great, if not then you know to look elsewhere.  It may be that the information is not accessible.

Comment: @TnTinMn, thank you very much for your time and help.  I'll take a look at it and hopefully it leads me to a solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I've finally done it!  Thank you so much for pointing me at the right direction!