# Can you get a Word.Application Object for a specific Process?

Tags: ms-word, marshalling, .net-4.8

GetActiveObject and variations thereof (e.g. through Marshaling) can be used to fetch a **Word.Application** object. If WINWORD.EXE is already running, that will give me the Word.Application object for that process. All good.... **BUT**

What if - for whatever reason - there are multiple WINWORD.EXE processes already running in the current Windows Session? I might use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD"), ignore any where the .SessionID does not equal System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionID ... and I might find 2 or more WINWORD processes running in the current session.

Say I get two WINWORD Processes, one with Id 1 and one with Id 2. Is there a way I can get the Word.Application object **explicitly** for the WINWORD process with Id 2?

Suggestions in **C# or VB** code equally welcome. Our code targets **.NET Framework version 4.8**

And I accept that the answer may be "You can't do that". A valid answer is a valid answer, even if I don't like it.

Comment: Word is a single-instance process, so this condition does not normally occur.  It is technically possible to encounter more than one, if another process automates Word (like you are trying to do).  In which case you have to [consult the ROT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table) to find the one that has the document of interest loaded.  Lots of very ugly corner-cases, beyond the user's security software, best avoided completely.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I'd be happy for you to post something along those lines as an answer. What I am dealing with is an edge case at best, where our Automation doesn't work because a Word process is "stuck" somewhere in the background. Explaining the Task Manager to users is a lost cause so I am going to employ the blunt instrument of just killing any WINWORD processes if the user chooses to do so, consequences be damned LOL

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Ah no. You gave a perfectly valid answer to the original question: "you have to consult the ROT to find the one that has the document of interest loaded. Lots of very ugly corner-cases, beyond the user's security software, best avoided completely." - that's a good answer. That I conclude from that that I'm better off not trying is neither here nor there.