# Windows Running Object Table - Admin vs User Mode

Tags: c#, com, ole

I'm writing a c# application that is trying to get a COM object pointer to another (separately running) application **under the same user**. From my experiments, it seems that the windows [Running Object Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-irunningobjecttable) will only show processes running in the same execution mode - admin or user.

When I run my app in User mode, the below code will work if the other application is *also* running in User mode, and likewise for admin/admin. When the modes are different, however, I cannot see the other application. Here I'm using [Marshal.GetActiveObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?view=netframework-4.8), but I get the same results when using the Moniker/BindCtx method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irunningobjecttable-enumrunning) and [here](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/12/accessing-com-applications-from-the-running-object-table.html).

```
string progID = "other-application-prog-id";

// obj != null when myApp and otherApp are running at the same privilege level,
//   and obj == null when privilege levels are different
Object obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject(progID);
```

I expect the behavior to be the following:

| My App Mode | Other App Mode | Behavior of GetActiveObject() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User | User | **obj** |
| User | Admin | **null** |
| Admin | User | **obj** |
| Admin | Admin | **obj** |

However the observed is:

| My App Mode | Other App Mode | Behavior of GetActiveObject() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User | User | **obj** |
| User | Admin | **null** |
| Admin | User | **null** |
| Admin | Admin | **obj** |

This seems like unintended behavior, especially because it goes against [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table#:%7E:text=When%20running%20with%20escalated%20priviliges%2C%20you%20can%20see%20all%20processes%20belonging%20to%20all%20users) answer  (albeit from 10 years ago). Is there any way to get the User Running Object Table entries when running as Admin?

Comment: Please [edit] post to make it clear if you are talking about processes running under different accounts or elevated under the same account?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm talking about processes under the same account.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. You can tweak some of it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-com-elevation-moniker